# .Net Core Entity Framework Linq Fluent API query doesn't create/execute correct SQL query ran on database

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I wrote this SQL query:

```
SELECT R.Name, R.PointsNeeded, A.EmailAddress, SUM(PH.Points) AS TotalPoints
FROM Business AS B
INNER JOIN Reward AS R ON R.BusinessId = B.Id
INNER JOIN Account AS A ON A.BusinessId = B.Id
INNER JOIN PointHistory PH ON PH.AccountId = A.Id
WHERE B.Serial = 'F5C17337-F675-4270-8A57-FE2F5782B5CB'
GROUP BY R.Name, A.EmailAddress, R.PointsNeeded
HAVING SUM(PH.Points) >= R.PointsNeeded
ORDER BY A.EmailAddress ASC
```

Which returns 3 results. I wanted to create this using linq/fluent api. I wasn't able to figure out how to do `HAVING` so I created this:

```
var eligableAccounts = _context.Business
           .Join(_context.Reward, B => B.Id, R => R.BusinessId, (Business, Rewards) => new { Business, Rewards })
           .Join(_context.Account, BusinessRewards => BusinessRewards.Business.Id, A => A.BusinessId, (BusinessRewards, Account) => new
           {
               Business = BusinessRewards.Business,
               Rewards = BusinessRewards.Rewards,
               Account = Account
           })
            .Join(_context.PointHistory, Model => Model.Account.Id, PointHistory => PointHistory.AccountId, (Model, PointHistory) => new
            {
                Business = Model.Business,
                Rewards = Model.Rewards,
                Account = Model.Account,
                PointHistory = PointHistory
            })
            .Where(Model => Model.Business.Serial == businessSerial)
            .GroupBy(Model => new { Model.Rewards.Name, Model.Account.EmailAddress, Model.Rewards.PointsNeeded })
            .Where(Group => Group.Sum(Model => Model.PointHistory.Points) >= Group.Key.PointsNeeded)
            .Select(Group => new {
                TotalPoints = Group.Sum(Model => Model.PointHistory.Points),
                EmailAddress = Group.Key.EmailAddress,
                RewardName = Group.Key.Name,
                PointsNeeded = Group.Key.PointsNeeded
            }).ToList();
```

This works and `eligableAccounts` contains the same 3 results that my SQL query returns when executing directly in SQL Management Studio. I wanted to see what is ran behind the scenes and to my surprise, every result set is returned and then .net is doing some magic sauce to get only the 3 records that I required. Here is what EF is is actually executing on the database:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [B].[Id], [B].[Code], [B].[LastProcessedDateTime], [B].[Name], [B].[PointRatio], [B].[Serial], [Rewards].[Id], [Rewards].[BusinessId], [Rewards].[Name], [Rewards].[PointsNeeded], [Account].[Id], [Account].[BusinessId], [Account].[City], [Account].[Created], [Account].[EmailAddress], [Account].[EmailSent], [Account].[FirstName], [Account].[LastName], [Account].[Password], [Account].[PasswordSalt], [Account].[Phone], [Account].[RoleId], [Account].[State], [Account].[Updated], [Account].[VerificationCode], [Account].[Verified], [Account].[ZipCode], [PointHistory].[Id], [PointHistory].[AccountId], [PointHistory].[Points], [PointHistory].[TransactionDate], [PointHistory].[TransactionType]
FROM [Business] AS [B]
INNER JOIN [Reward] AS [Rewards] ON [B].[Id] = [Rewards].[BusinessId]
INNER JOIN [Account] AS [Account] ON [B].[Id] = [Account].[BusinessId]
INNER JOIN [PointHistory] AS [PointHistory] ON [Account].[Id] = [PointHistory].[AccountId]
WHERE [B].[Serial] = @__businessSerial_0
ORDER BY [Rewards].[Name], [Account].[EmailAddress], [Rewards].[PointsNeeded]',N'@__businessSerial_0 nvarchar(4000)',@__businessSerial_0=N'F5C17337-F675-4270-8A57-FE2F5782B5CB'
```

This SQL when executed directly on the database returns all results because the `HAVING` statement isn't being created by EF. Does anyone know how I can write my EF code to produce the correct query that gets executed? This will likely start returning hundreds of thousands of records and I do not like the idea of .net handling the reduction of the result set in memory. I'd rather push that off to the database. If I have to create a stored procedure I can do that, but don't really want to. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately EF Core does not translate `GroupBy` to SQL yet, so there is nothing you can do currently. It's committed to be included in next EF Core release 2.1 (Q4 2017) - see **GroupBy translation** item in their [Roadmap](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/wiki/Roadmap)

Answer (score 0):

While I can't fix EF Core's limitations (unless you want to switch to full EF), it is possible to convert your SQL to LINQ. I find it easier to use query syntax for grouping like this:

```
var ans = from b in _context.Business
          join r in _context.Reward on b.Id equals r.BusinessId
          join a in _context.Account on b.Id equals a.BusinessId
          join ph in _context.PointHistory on a.Id equals ph.AccountId
          where b.Serial == "F5C17337-F675-4270-8A57-FE2F5782B5CB"
          group new { b, r, a, ph } by new { r.Name, a.EmailAddress, r.PointsNeeded } into grp
          let TotalPoints = grp.Sum(g => g.ph.Points)
          where TotalPoints >= grp.Key.PointsNeeded
          orderby grp.Key.EmailAddress
          select new { grp.Key.Name, grp.Key.PointsNeeded, grp.Key.EmailAddress, TotalPoints };
```

Note the translation is straight forward and almost mechanical.

Your translation with lambda syntax looks as straight forward to me.